# Is it possible to run selenium rc code in 2 different URLs?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

The AUT contains the login page which validates the user credentials. Once successful, the user needs to hit a new URL in a new tab to access the actual application.

Is it possible to automate the above scenario using selenium RC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but I'd recommend using Selenium WebDriver as it's the current version.  Selenium RC is very old.

Using Selenium WebDriver:

```
driver.navigate().to("http://aut/login");
driver.... // login logic like setting the user/pass clicking login.
...

driver.navigate().to("http://somenewurl.com");
// continue testing here...
```

If you are adamant on remaining with Selenium 1 (which i could understand if you already have a big suite in it..):

```
selenium.open("http://aut/login");
selenium... // login logic here
...

selenium.open("http://somenewurl.com");
// continue testing here.
```